# An interesting series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+3)^n-1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here is an interesting series that unexpectedly (at least to me) evaluates to a nice value, that is

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+3)^n-1}=1-\log(2)$$

As you can see, it's not one of the series we meet here daily, and I suppose the ways to approach
it might be a good lesson to learn. Any hint, clue for a good starting point is welcome.

*Here is a supplementary question: Find the closed form of*

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3k+4)^n-1}$$

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate it yourself? If not, how do you know what the answer is?

Comment: I know this may sound rather silly, but, just out of curiosity, have you tried expanding the summand into a third infinite series?

Comment: @TonyK there are a whole damn lot of methods

Comment: @Lucian I simply missed to think of that. Let me give it a try. Thanks (+1)

Comment: @UserX: What does that have to do with my comment?

Comment: @TonyK *How?* I was told the answer, but not the solution.

Comment: Let $S_{\pm}(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+3)^n\pm 1}$. Then, $S_{-}(2n)=\frac{1}{2}(S_-(n)-S_+(n))$. But I don't if this helps...

Comment: Are you sure it converges to the specified value?

Comment: @AleksVlasev yeah. Do you suspect it converges to another value?

Comment: Well, if you expand the geometric series $\sum_{m=1}^\infty (2k+1)^{-mn}$, switch the order of summation you get that the whole sum should be

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} 2^{-mn} \zeta_{3/2}(mn)$$

One can try getting rid of the $m = 1$ term to get something symmetric. The $m = 1$ term is, according to mathematica

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\zeta_{3/2}(n) = 1- \log(2)$$

Which should mean the other piece should be 0 but it's made up of positive terms so it won't be zero.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{(2k+3)^n-1}=\frac{1}{(2k+3)^n}+\frac{1}{(2k+3)^{2n}}+\frac{1}{(2k+3)^{3n}}+\ldots$$
and summing over $n$:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+3)^n-1}=\frac{\frac{1}{(2k+3)^2}}{1-\frac{1}{2k+3}}+\frac{\frac{1}{(2k+3)^4}}{1-\frac{1}{(2k+3)^2}}+\frac{\frac{1}{(2k+3)^6}}{1-\frac{1}{(2k+3)^3}}+\ldots$$
and summing over $k$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+3)^n-1}=(1-\log 2)+\frac{1}{8}(10-\pi^2)+\ldots $$
so the first sum is greater than $1-\log 2$.

Comment: By that reasoning the other one should be $> 1-\tfrac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}-\tfrac{\log(3)}{2}$